# Posts in Admin only display 1 Post instead of all

Tags: posts, admin

When I run wp-admin/edit.php I normally should get a list of all Posts.

WordPress 4.3.1 running Avada Child theme.

But I only get the last Post in the list.

All (8) | Published (7) | Draft (1)

As you can see there are 8 in total and 7 Published.

Has someone an idea how to get all Posts in the list?

Comment: What is **Number of items per page** set to under **Screen Options** tab? Do you have any `pre_get_posts` hooks that may be accidentally targeting admin screens?

Comment: Number of items per page was set to 1! Problem solved/ Thanks Milo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Number of items per page was set to 1! Problem solved